# Java Scanner Regex InputMistmastchException

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I've read a few other posts put can't figure out inherently what is wrong with the following code and why does it throw an exception:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(" 0 B 2 # L");

    String first = scanner.next("[0-9]+ [abB#]");
    String second = scanner.next("[0-9]+ [abB#] [LR]");

    System.out.println(first); 
    System.out.println(second);

}
```

Expected output:

```
0 B
2 # L
```

Answer (score 2):

Quoting javadoc of [`Scanner.next(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28java.lang.String%29):

> Returns the next token if it matches the pattern constructed from the specified string.

By default (and you didn't change that), the `Scanner` will split tokens on white-space, so the tokens returned by the `Scanner` are:

```
"0"
"B"
"2"
"#"
"L"
```

The first `next` token is `"0"` and that doesn't match `"[0-9]+ [abB#]"`, so you get `InputMismatchException`.

**Solution**

Don't use a `Scanner`.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(" *([0-9]+ [abB#]) +([0-9]+ [abB#] [LR]) *");
Matcher m = p.matcher(" 0 B 2 # L");
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

Comment: So even tho the pattern matching contains a space to consume the space in the string java has already tokenized the string for comparison?

Comment: Java hasn't, `Scanner` has, as documented in `next(String)`, or rather, it hasn't consumed anything yet. You might try [`findInLine(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findInLine%28java.lang.String%29) or [`findWithinHorizon(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findWithinHorizon%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), or skip using `Scanner` and just parse the entire String using regex.

Answer (score 2):

When using [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), it delimits the whole input. In your case, it delimits with whitespace (default):

> A `Scanner` breaks its input into tokens using **a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace**.

@Andreas described the root cause of the exception.

Now, the solution is to use methods that disregard delimiters.

> The [`findInLine(java.lang.String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findInLine(java.lang.String)), [`findWithinHorizon(java.lang.String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findWithinHorizon(java.lang.String,%20int)), and [`skip(java.util.regex.Pattern)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#skip(java.util.regex.Pattern)) methods operate independently of the delimiter pattern. These methods will attempt to match the specified pattern with no regard to delimiters in the input and thus can be used in special circumstances where delimiters are not relevant.

You can use [`Scanner.findInLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findInLine(java.util.regex.Pattern)):

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(" 0 B 2 # L");
String first = s.findInLine("[0-9]+ [abB#]"); // => 0 B
System.out.println(first);
String second = s.findInLine("[0-9]+ [abB#] [LR]"); // => 2 # L
System.out.println(second);
s.close();
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/K6g5Sk)

A simple `Matcher` regex solution:

```
String str = " 0 B 2 # L";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+ [abB#] [LR]|[0-9]+ [abB#]");
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/9T1VJC)

**The longer alternative must come before the shorter one to obtain correct matches.**

Comment: this was twhat i used in my original solution I just didn't like if it was parsing the string "0 q 2 # L" for example first would match to "2 #" and then second would return null, but if thats the implementation then i suppose thats the way I need to work with it

Comment: I updated my answer with a simple `Matcher` regex solution. Note how the alternatives are placed: longer is first, shorter is second.